# Apache Ignite instance as Spark Broad cast variable

Tags: apache-spark, ignite

Once Ignite is instantiated at Driver using,

```
Ignite ignite = Ignition.getOrStart(igniteConfiguration);
```

Need to broadcast this ignite instance to all executors as a broadcast variable, Let me know if If I can achieve this. I know that Ignite is not Serialize but is there any way to make it serialize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ignite instance cannot be broadcasted between executors, since it corresponds to a node running locally. An object itself sent to another executor won't do you any good.

There is a special integration between Apache Ignite and Apache Spark: https://apacheignite-fs.readme.io/docs
If you use this integration, then every Spark executor will start an Ignite node, and you'll be able to work with it. Usually IgniteRDD or Ignite data frames are used to work with Ignite from Spark. You can also get Ignite instance using IgniteContext#ignite() method.

For more information refer to the documentation: https://apacheignite-fs.readme.io/docs/ignitecontext-igniterdd